# Wrap Object into a function

Tags: javascript

How can I turn this piece of code into a function that accept an element as a parameter for example:

```
$('#nav-btn li')
                .vel('slideUp', 
                  { 
                    duration: 800, 
                    opacity: 1, 
                    stagger: 150 
                  });
```

functionName('#nav-btn li');

functionName('#otherElement2');

functionName('#otherElement3');

Comment: `function functionName(parameter) { ... }` I suggest to read a tutorial about functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function functionName(elId){
    $(elId).vel('slideUp', 
                  { 
                    duration: 800, 
                    opacity: 1, 
                    stagger: 150 
                  });
}
```

Now use

```
functionName('#nav-btn li');

functionName('#otherElement2');

functionName('#otherElement3');
```

Comment: Good, but your parameter name elId implies that you are passing just the id (not the #).  It might be better to pass just the string ID and append the id selector # inside the function.

Comment: @Seano666 , it depends. The best way would be to pass the jQuery Object itself like `functionName($("#whatever"))`, but that is not what OP has asked for.